# Best way to raise reputation without spamming questions?

Tags: discussion

I would like to be able to post a photo to my question, how can I work to raise my reputation so I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just upload the images to a site like [imgur](http://imgur.com) and provide links in your post. Someone with more reputation will edit them in. Taking the time to write you question well should get you a couple of upvotes, and with it the necessary reputation for next time :)

Note that there is also a reputation based limit on the number of links you can have in one post, if you need to you can create a imgur "album" or put a few extra links in comments. Again, writing a good question in the first place should easily boost you over the limits.

Comment: or in a comment, isn't there limits on links in posts?

Comment: I actually thought of this and did it moments before you posted it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mateo I believe there is a limit of 2 links, yes. That should lift after a couple of upvotes as well. Good point.